# Type of Holder Inequality

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality

I am struggling to find a proof of the following inequality which is a modification of the generalized Holder inequality

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ a mesurable space. Let  $ \alpha \in [0,1]$ and $p,q,r\in ]0,\infty]$ such that  $\frac{\alpha}{p} + \frac{1- \alpha}{q} = \frac{1}{r}$,  $f \in L^r(\Omega)$. Then $$||f||_{L^r} \leq ||f||_{L^p}^{\alpha}||f||_{L^q}^{1-\alpha}.$$
I followed the method shown in the post [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145771/understanding-generalized-holder-inequality-proof).

No results anticipated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: Write $$|f|^r=|f|^{\alpha r}|f|^{(1-\alpha)r}.$$ I think you also need $f\in L^p\cap L^q $. See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/amp/

Comment: Thank you for precious help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $q  < \infty$; we can write
$$
\lvert f \rvert^r =\lvert f \rvert^{p \frac{\alpha r}{p}}\cdot \lvert f \rvert^{q\frac{(1-\alpha)r}{q}} 
$$
since $\frac{p}{\alpha r} > 1$, we apply Holder's inequality
$$
\lVert \lvert f \rvert^r \rVert_1 \leqslant \lVert \lvert f \rvert^{\alpha r} \rVert_{\frac{p}{\alpha r}} \cdot \lVert \lvert f \rvert^{(1-\alpha) r} \rVert_{\frac{q}{(1-\alpha) r}}
$$
Hence 
$$
\lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_r^r \leqslant \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_{p}^{\alpha r} \cdot \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_q^{(1-\alpha)r} \quad  \text{and} \quad  \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_r \leqslant \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_{p}^{\alpha } \cdot \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_q^{(1-\alpha)}. 
$$
If $q = \infty$ then $\lvert f \rvert^r =\lvert f \rvert^p \cdot \lvert f \rvert^{r-p} \leqslant \lvert f \rvert^p \cdot \lvert f \rvert_{\infty}^{r-p}$
almost every where since $\alpha=\frac{p}{r}$, then
$$
\lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_r \leqslant \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_{p}^{\alpha } \cdot \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert_{\infty}^{(1-\alpha)}. 
$$